# Rearrangement lemma in normal ordering

Tags: conformal-field-theory, wick-theorem

I try to calculate energy-momentum tensor from Sugawara construction of Wakimoto representation for $SU(2)_k$ current in 2d CFT. but at first I have to understand rearrangement lemma. so can anybody tell me what happens here? parentheses are normal ordering here.

[image: rearrangement lemma]

Answer (score 1):

The need for rearrangement lemmas comes from the fact that a bare product of local operators at the same point is not well defined. Instead, normal ordered products are defined by *point splitting*. That is, we write $A(z)B(w)$ (regularization), subtract all inverse powers of $z-w$ (renormalization) and then take $z \to w$. As such, the normal ordered product is the first regular term in the OPE
\begin{equation}
A(z)B(w) = \sum_{r = r_0}^\infty \{ AB \}_r(w) (z-w)^r
\end{equation}
which is $\{ AB \}_0$. To see how this works in your first non-trivial example, we take $\beta(z)$ and contract it with $(\gamma \partial \varphi)(w)$ using Wick's theorem. This produces one singular term and then regular terms which start at $(\beta (\gamma \partial \varphi))$ by definition.
\begin{equation}
\beta(z) (\gamma \partial \varphi)(w) = \frac{\partial \varphi(w)}{z-w} + (\beta (\gamma \partial \varphi))(w) + \dots
\end{equation}
Proceeding in the other order, however, we get
\begin{align}
(\gamma \partial \varphi)(z) \beta(w) &= -\frac{\partial \varphi(z)}{z - w} + ((\gamma \varphi) \beta)(w) + \dots \\
&= -\frac{\partial \varphi(w)}{z - w} - \partial^2 \varphi(w) + ((\gamma \varphi) \beta)(w) + \dots
\end{align}
which has one more term since we Taylor expanded until all operators on the right side were evaluated at $w$. Comparing the two now reproduces your second equation.

Clearly, the difference comes about because $\beta$ and $(\gamma \partial \varphi)$ have a non-identity singular term in their OPE, namely $\partial \varphi$. More generally, all such terms contribute to the normal ordered commutator as in
\begin{equation}
(AB)(z) - (BA)(z) = \sum_{r < 0} (-1)^{r + 1} \frac{1}{|r|!} \partial^{|r|} \{ AB \}_r(z).
\end{equation}
This is a formula from https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9210010 with a small typo fixed. Something else you can find in sources like this is an equivalent formula in terms of modes.
\begin{equation}
(AB)_n = \sum_{k > -h_B} A_{n - k} B_k + \sum_{k \leq -h_B} B_k A_{n - k}
\end{equation}
This is a lot like what we do in free field theory by putting oscillators that annihilate the vacuum on the right. Applying this to the same example and using the fact that $(\gamma \partial \varphi) = (\partial \varphi \gamma)$,
\begin{align}
(\beta(\gamma \partial \varphi))_n - ((\gamma \partial \varphi) \beta)_n &= \sum_{k > -\frac{1}{2}} \sum_l \beta_{n - k} \gamma_l \alpha_{k - l} + \sum_{k \leq -\frac{1}{2}} \sum_l \gamma_l \alpha_{k - l} \beta_{n - k} \\
&- \sum_{k > -\frac{3}{2}} \sum_l \gamma_l \alpha_{n - k - l} \beta_k - \sum_{k \leq -\frac{3}{2}} \sum_l \beta_k \gamma_l \alpha_{n - k - l} \\
&= \left ( \sum_{k \leq -\frac{1}{2}} - \sum_{k < n + \frac{3}{2}} \right ) \sum_l \gamma_l \alpha_{k - l} \beta_{n - k} + \left ( \sum_{k > -\frac{1}{2}} - \sum_{k \geq n + \frac{3}{2}} \right ) \sum_l \beta_{n - k} \gamma_l \alpha_{k - l}.
\end{align}
To get the last line, we re-indexed two sums with $k \to n - k$. Clearly, both terms in parentheses are sums from $k = \frac{1}{2}, \dots, n + \frac{1}{2}$. But in writing these out, we recognize the commutator and get
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k = \frac{1}{2}}^{n + \frac{1}{2}} \sum_l [\beta_{n - k}, \gamma_l] \alpha_{k - l} = -\sum_{k = \frac{1}{2}}^{n + \frac{1}{2}} \alpha_n = -(n + 1) \alpha_n.
\end{equation}
These are just the modes of $\partial^2 \varphi$. This is enough to solve the other nested products after a bit more calculation. There is also a helpful Mathematica package by Thielemans called OPEdefs.